# Nuxt computed value not evaluated on client side

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, computed-properties

I notice that my computed doesn't have the same value if I use it in a svg with a `v-bind` or with a `{{}}`

Here my CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-breeze-emdk6?file=/pages/index.vue

the `r` value of my circle seems incorrect, at least it's different than the `<p>`. Not sure how to handle this case.

Comment: the code `if (!process.client)` it will not execute at client side. so how will you get the correct value. do you want to execute it on server side?

Comment: @MdMahamudulHasan Yes. On the server side it should be 10px, and 100px on the client. The problem is that it not equals to 100px on the client side for the svg element, only the `<p>` is will computed